# Converting Json to CSV in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, json, csv

**Json:**

```
[  
   {  
      "to_name":"Voice Portal",
      "start_time":"2017-03-14 14:14:46 +0000"
   },
   {  
      "to_name":"Voice Portal-1",
      "start_time":"2017-03-14 14:14:46 +0000"
   },
   {  
      "to_name":"Voice Portal-2",
      "start_time":"2017-03-14 14:14:46 +0000"
   }
]
```

**Code:**

```
File jsonInputFile = new File("D:\\Java-CallLog\\src\\EdgeNode\\Calllog.json");
        InputStream is;
        try {               
            is = new FileInputStream(jsonInputFile);

            // Create JsonReader from Json.
            JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(is);
            // Get the JsonObject structure from JsonReader.
            JsonArray callLogArray = reader.readArray();
            reader.close();
            System.out.println(callLogArray.size());

            String csv = null;
            File file=new File("D:\\Java-CallLog\\src\\EdgeNode\\Calllog.csv");
            for (int i = 0; i<callLogArray.size(); i++){
                JsonObject obj = callLogArray.getJsonObject(i);                 
                String name = obj.getString("to_name");
                String startTime = obj.getString("start_time");
                System.out.println(name);      

                 csv = CDL.toString(obj);                   
                FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
            }           

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Let me know what am missing in the above code.

yes, i have added into the loop. Following error am getting Error: The method toString(JSONArray) in the type CDL is not applicable for the arguments (JsonObject) FileUtils cannot be resolved

Expected output: --------------------- Voice Portal, 2017-03-14 14:14:46 +0000 Voice Portal-1,2017-03-14 14:14:46 +0000 Voice Portal-2,2017-03-14 14:14:46 +0000

Comment: Please edit your question to include the errors

Comment: `obj` is not within scope... It's only defined *within* the loop

Comment: yes, i have added into the loop. Following error am getting

Error:
The method toString(JSONArray) in the type CDL is not applicable for the arguments (JsonObject)
 FileUtils cannot be resolved

Comment: - Expected output:
---------------------
`Voice Portal, 2017-03-14 14:14:46 +0000
Voice Portal-1,2017-03-14 14:14:46 +0000
Voice Portal-2,2017-03-14 14:14:46 +0000`

Comment: If you've added to the loop, then [edit] the question with the correct code

Comment: I have added the code into the loop and corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation (https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/commons/json/util/CDL.html) says that the method toString() of class CDL expects an org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONArray as a parameter. But you are using javax.json.JsonReader's readArray() method which returns a javax.json.JsonArray.

And anyway you already have name and startTime as Strings. It's just a matter of giving them the desired format. You could try this for example to build the csv string.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(...){
    ...
    sb.append(name).append(",").append(startTime).append(" ");
}   
csv = sb.toString();
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
```

Note the writeStringToFile() line is outside of the loop.